# visual c++ 2012 application won't run under windows xp - updated

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

hello and welcom every one

am using visual c++ 2012 ultimate with the update 3, i have a project should be executed in an  xp pack 3 envirement, i change the toolset as explained in this blog
[Windows XP Targeting with visual studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx)

on my windows xp machine i install svcedit.exe visual 2012 update 3, but the probleme is that the code couldn't run, and show me no error at all.

i don't really no what the probleme is!!

Example - Source file

**main.cpp**

```
#include <WindowsX.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "resource1.h"

#define my_PROCESS_MESSAGE(hWnd, message, fn)   \
    case(message):  \
        return( \
            SetDlgMsgResult(hWnd, uMsg, \
                HANDLE_##message((hWnd), (wParam), (lParam), (fn)) ))   \

LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
BOOL Cls_OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam);
void Cls_OnCommand(HWND hwnd, int id, HWND hwndCtl, UINT codeNotify);

int WINAPI _tWinMain(   HINSTANCE   hInstance,
                HINSTANCE,
                LPTSTR,
                int         iCmdShow    )
{
    DialogBoxParam( hInstance,
            MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DLLINJECTOR),
            NULL,
            (DLGPROC) DlgProc,
            NULL
            );

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(   HWND    hWnd,
                            UINT    uMsg,
                            WPARAM  wParam,
                            LPARAM  lParam  )
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        my_PROCESS_MESSAGE(hWnd, WM_INITDIALOG, Cls_OnInitDialog);
        my_PROCESS_MESSAGE(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, Cls_OnCommand);

    default:
        break;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

BOOL Cls_OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam)
{
    SetDlgItemText( hwnd,
            IDC_DEBUG,
            _T("Zirek: Some text\r\n")
            );

    return TRUE;
}

void Cls_OnCommand(HWND hwnd, int id, HWND hwndCtl, UINT codeNotify)
{
    switch (id)
    {
    case IDCANCEL:
        EndDialog(hwnd, id);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return;
}
```

**resource1.h**

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by Resource.rc
//
#define IDCANCEL2                       3
#define IDCANCEL3                       4
#define IDD_DIALOG1                     101
#define IDD_DLLINJECTOR                 101
#define IDC_TREE1                       1001
#define IDC_EDIT1                       1002
#define IDC_DEBUG                       1003
#define IDC_LIST1                       1004
#define IDC_EDIT4                       1005
#define IDC_EDIT3                       1007

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        102
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1006
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

Resource.rc

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource1.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource1.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_DLLINJECTOR DIALOGEX 0, 0, 559, 255
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "DLL Injector"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "&Close",IDCANCEL,494,54,50,14
    CONTROL         "",IDC_TREE1,"SysTreeView32",WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP,7,7,125,221,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,7,234,125,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL,WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    EDITTEXT        IDC_DEBUG,138,149,414,99,ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    CONTROL         "",IDC_LIST1,"SysListView32",LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,138,7,125,137,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    CTEXT           "Zirek\r\nAT4RE\r\nDLL Injector",IDC_STATIC,486,23,66,26,0,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT3,269,130,226,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL,WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME
    PUSHBUTTON      "&Inject",IDCANCEL2,494,74,50,29
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT4,269,7,211,117,ES_AUTOHSCROLL,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "&Open",IDCANCEL3,502,130,50,14
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_DLLINJECTOR, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 552
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 248
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

the code run correctly on windows 8 and windows 7, but in windows xp whene i click the application nothing happen at all.

Best,
Zirek

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect us to do to help you. We have no access to anything to help debug the problem, as we don't have any of your code, no absolutely nothing about what it does or depends on, and have no information available to try and figure it out. How **exactly** do you think we can help with zero information or access?

Comment: Sory for that, source file included

Comment: It does not appear that you ever called `InitCommonControls` which is required for using a tree control.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [VC++ 2012 Redistributables](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) on any machine where you want to run the application. Make sure you download and install the redistributables that match your Visual Studio version including Update (for instance, if you have VS2012 Update 2, distribute that version, not the redistributables for VS2013 Update 3).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is either, but in general using [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) is a good start. It will tell you if your app depends on functions not available in winxp, or if you forgot to deploy some runtime dll.

Comment: i share the source code, i only use windows api, i think the probleme is in my resource file, but i have no idea how to read it.